# Problems turning a Long into a String out of a SharedPreferance

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences, long-integer

Yeah that is a mouthful. Alright so now I am trying to send a message using the long I placed into a shared pref before. I am wondering the best way to get this done... I get an error with the following code:

```
shortMessageManager.sendTextMessage(prefs.getLong(constants.myNumber), null, message, null, null);
```

I get the following error:
getLong (String, long) in SharedPreference can not be applied to (String)

So how do I go about making the long a string to be used?

I already tried the prefs.getLong(constants.myNumber.toString()) method but that did not yield anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code where you save the long and get the long using the SharedPreferance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a `long` to `String` use `String.valueOf()`

**Edited:** To convert `String` to `long` use `Long.parseLong(*)`

Also you may use something like `String b = stringA + longC`, for example `String a = ""+6L`

Comment: To convert a String to long (lower case), preferably use Long.parseLong()

Comment: Sorry I did not get back to you on this - I went away from keyboard and only just now got back. - Thanks for the awesome answer it worked like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parameter in your getLong() call:

```
getLong(prefNameKey, fallbackValue);
```